# How to change the default location where new post gets stored?

Tags: pages, redirect, urls, site-url

Traditionally, in WordPress after we write a new post it is stored in the location (URL) as followed:

[www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) / best-headphones-of-2023

But what if we want to store that new post after one more hierarchy like:

[www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) / blog / best-headphones-of-2023

Please note that here I'm not talking about creating a category page and then posting that link on the homepage.

How to achieve this?  And which particular setting needs to be tweaked?

Answer (score 0):

I would look in permalink settings in your wp-admin dashboard.
That's where you can alter url structures of your WordPress site including how post urls are determined.
I think that's all you would need depending on your theme.

[image: Permalink Settings]